# multiple radio groups with only one allowed selection?

Tags: android, android-layout, onclick

For layout purposes I have three radiogroups with multiple selections in each group.  How can I code so that only one choice is allowed, across all three groups?

In other words, right now I can make a selection in each group for a total of 3 selections.  I want these to "see" each other and only allow one selection total.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the method:

```
private RadioButton lastCheckedRB = null;
//whatever code

 //onClicklistener for radiogroup does not work
 RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener listener = new  RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            RadioButton checked_rb = (RadioButton) group.findViewById(checkedId);
            //OnCheckedChangeListener checks for reclick of a clicked rb, so the rest of the code is not executed
            if (lastCheckedRB != null) {
                lastCheckedRB.setChecked(false);
            }
            //store the clicked radiobutton
            lastCheckedRB = checked_rb;
        }
    };
 radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
 radioGroup2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(listener);
```